# A product of a convergent sequence by a bounded sequence, but the limit of the convergent sequence is not $0$, is always divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ a sequence converging to $L\neq 0$, and let $(b_n)$ a divergent, but bounded, sequence. Is it true that $(a_nb_n)$ is always a divergent sequence or can I find an example where $(a_nb_n)$ converges?

I tried to prove this, but proving divergence is very hard to me, as I dont even know how to choose a proper $\epsilon$. Also tried a lot of examples, all of them diverging.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $(b_n)$ is bounded but divergent, say it as two subsequences converging to two different limits (if not, it would be convergent) $L_1$ and $L_2$. The two corresponding subsequences of $(a_n\cdot b_n)$ will converge to $LL_1$ and $LL_2$ that are different if $L \neq 0$. Thus $(a_n\cdot b_n)$ is divergent.